# I want to load array data from parse (swift)

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform, pfquery, pfobject

I have to make a Comment, being an attempt to import the Array in the Parse. However, there is a problem.

When i try to load array from Parse, my output is ("Blah","Blah","Blah") 
It's a tuple.... not a Array TT.....

How Can I bring in the Array from Parse Correctly?

it's my fetch function from parse

```
func fetchDataFromParse(){

    var query = PFQuery(className:"Cafe")

    query.whereKey("name", notEqualTo: "")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {

        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.

            // Do something with the found objects
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {

                for object in objects {

                    self.imageText.append(object.objectForKey("name")! as! String)

                    self.commentArray = (object.objectForKey("comment")!)  // This is array of comment from Parse!!

                    self.imageFiles.append(object.objectForKey("imageFile") as! PFFile)

                    self.messageTableView.reloadData()

                }

            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
        }
    }




}
```

Comment: How are you declaring "commentArray"? Also, could you edit your question with a screenShot from your parse "Cafe" class?

Comment: I can't upload my image because of reputation TT.

Comment: there is my uploaded file  http://blog.naver.com/kkyy3402/220478832040

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use the following to cast this as a Swift Array:

> self.commentArray = object.objectForKey("comment") as? [AnyObject]